# How to calculate forces between individual atoms in OpenMM

Tags: python

I am new to **OpenMM** and I would appreciate some guidance on the following matter:

Currently I am not interested in running molecular dynamics simulations, for starters I would just like to compute what are the forces or free energies between individual pairs of atoms using  OpenMMs AMBER force field for example. Essentially I would like to end up with a heat map which represents forces between atom pairs something like this:
[image]
Where  numbers represent strength of the force or value of free energy.

I have trouble finding out how to access such lower level functionality of OpenMM where I could write a custom script that calculates only desired forces provided the 3D coordinates of atoms and their types. In their tutorials I have just found how to run fully fledged simulations by providing force field data and PDB files of molecular systems.

Preferably I would like to achieve this with python.

Any concrete example or guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found an answer in the [Openmm's issue tracker](https://github.com/openmm/openmm/issues/2682) on GitHub.

In short: There is no API to achieve exactly that in OpenMM as what I am trying to do is not well defined from purely physical/chemical perspective. My best bet is to compute something that looks like an energy based only on pairwise inter-atom distances which can be quarried from an openmm state like this (as suggested in the discussion referenced above):

```
state = simulation.context.getState(getPositions=True)
positions = state.getPositions(asNumpy=True).value_in_unit(nanometer)
```